# Proof that substitution of predicates in FOL formulas preserves validity

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the "Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning" by John Harrison ([site](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/atp/index.html)) there is an algorithm for the substitution of variables in a formula of first order logic using variable renaming and a proof that this preserves validity (see the bottom of this [file](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/atp/OCaml/fol.ml) and a formalization of the proof in Lean [here](https://github.com/pthomas505/lean3/blob/d892151aa112dd27bdf2cbaf11efec89d8ddb9f0/src/metalogic/pred.lean#L920-L1677)).

I am trying to find an equivalent function and proof for the substitution of predicates, such as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374736/is-there-a-rule-for-uniform-substitution-of-predicate-symbols-in-fol/1374989#1374989).

Comment: Think semantically - from a countermodel for a substitution instance you can build a countermodel for the original sentence.

Comment: This is a straightforward structural induction on the proof.